# horizontal slider container positions up when page is called from url hash

Tags: jquery, horizontal-scrolling, parallax

If you view the page here @ http://8020indie.com/wp-content/uploads/TEC/ , 
you will see everything works fine, but when you access the page with a hash, such as http://8020indie.com/wp-content/uploads/TEC/index.htm#content2 , the horizontal positioning of the content div is off. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var width = '1000';
    var slides = 3;
    $('.main_inner').css({
        width: slides * width,
    });
    $('a.tab_link').click(function(){
        var contentNum = $(this).attr('rel');
        var marginToScroll = width * contentNum - width;
        $('.main_inner').animate({
        marginLeft: '-' + marginToScroll,
        }, 1000);
        return false;
    });
    jQuery('#parallax1').jparallax({mouseport:jQuery('#content1')},{xtravel: '15px',                     ytravel: '0px'},{xtravel: '15px', ytravel: '0px'}, {xtravel: '15px', ytravel: '0px'});
    jQuery('#parallax2').jparallax({mouseport:jQuery('#content1')},{xtravel: '15px', ytravel: '0px'},{xtravel: '15px', ytravel: '0px'}, {xtravel: '15px', ytravel: '0px'});
    jQuery('#parallax3').jparallax({mouseport:jQuery('#content1')},{xtravel: '15px', ytravel: '0px'},{xtravel: '15px', ytravel: '0px'}, {xtravel: '15px', ytravel: '0px'});
});

function changeMySrc(i) {
    if (i == 1) {
        document.getElementById("ui_tab").src="images/buttonUiOn.png";
        document.getElementById("design_tab").src="images/buttonDesignOff.png";
        document.getElementById("integration_tab").src="images/buttonIntegrationOff.png";
    }
    if (i == 2) {
        document.getElementById("ui_tab").src="images/buttonUiOff.png";
        document.getElementById("design_tab").src="images/buttonDesignOn.png";
        document.getElementById("integration_tab").src="images/buttonIntegrationOff.png";
    }  
    else if (i == 3) {
        document.getElementById("ui_tab").src="images/buttonUiOff.png";
        document.getElementById("design_tab").src="images/buttonDesignOff.png";
        document.getElementById("integration_tab").src="images/buttonIntegrationOn.png";
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you mean "vertical position".

Comment: Yes I do sorry about that . The vertical position if off you are correct.

Answer (score 0):

As you probably know, if the hash matches the name of an "a" tag, such as `<a name="content2"/>` , the browser would scroll down to it automatically.

In HTML5, if the hash matches the ID of **any DOM object**, the browser will scroll down to it.

That's not exactly what's happening here, but my guess is that the final position of your `content2` div is getting messed up due to that auto-scrolling. Do you really have to use a hash that matches the ID of the `div`? To avoid that, for example, you can use `window.location.hash` and map that to the actual div ID.

Comment: what is happening is people are entering the site using a hash for whatever reason. ideally i wanted to serve up that clicked state from the hash they used to enter the site. just noticed that if i use the #parallax2 it will go to content 2 as well, but is still positioned up.